# How to sort dictionary by its values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, tkinter

I'm working on excel file to show the data on new tkinter window. I want to sort the rows using the Agent column values and ditsplay it on tkinter window

I tried using condition and iteration but i can't do it properly.

Here is the data:

```
  Country       Port incoterm Capacity    Date Agent  $ value      Total
0   Japan   Yokohama      FOB    20ton  2019/5   Sam   2650.6  2650600.0
1   China     Ningbo      DAT    40ton  2019/1    Li   2650.6  2385540.0
2     USA  Baltimore      FOB    Other  2018/9  John   2650.6  4240960.0
3  Russia     Moscow      EXW    20ton  2019/1  Vlad   2650.6  2120480.0
4   Japan      Tokyo      FOB    20ton  2019/1   Sam   2650.6  2915660.0
5   Japan      Tokyo      FOB    20ton  2019/1  Dave   2650.6  3180720.0
6   China   Shanghai      EXW    40ton  2019/1    Li   2500.6  3128250.6
```

Here is the code:

```
data = pd.read_excel("example.xlsx")
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
a = df.loc[(df.Country == 'Japan') & (df.incoterm == 'FOB') & (df.Capacity 
== '20ton') & (df.Port == 'Tokyo')]
_a = pd.DataFrame(a)
root = Tk()

for agent in _a.itertuples():
    if agent.Agent is agent.Agent:
        temp_agent = '{0}'.format(agent.Agent)
        ttk.Label(root, text="Agent:"+temp_agent).pack()
        for data in _a.itertuples():
            temp_text = '{0} {1} - ({2})'.format(data.Country, 
            data.incoterm, data.Total)
            ttk.Label(root, text=temp_text).pack()
            print (temp_text)
mainloop()
```

Output:

```
Sam
Japan FOB - (2915660.0)
Japan FOB - (3180720.0)
Dave
Japan FOB - (2915660.0)
Japan FOB - (3180720.0)
```

Expected output:

```
Sam
Japan FOB - (2915660.0)
Dave
Japan FOB - (3180720.0)
```

Comment: what is you question ?

Comment: Sorry just edited it it seems my code was not showing for some reasons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need the second loop.

Use:

```
_a = df.loc[(df.Country == 'Japan') & (df.incoterm == 'FOB') & (df.Capacity == '20ton') & (df.Port == 'Tokyo')]

for agent in _a.itertuples():
    if agent.Agent is agent.Agent:
        temp_agent = '{0}'.format(agent.Agent)
        print(temp_agent)
        temp_text = '{0} {1} - ({2})'.format(agent.Country, agent.incoterm, agent.Total)
        print (temp_text)
```

**Output:**

```
Sam
Japan FOB - (2915660.0)
Dave
Japan FOB - (3180720.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for key, value in sorted(mydict.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]):
    print("%s: %s" % (key, value))
```

if you want to sort it by value this might help. it will be sorted by key and its value and it will iterate in whole dict. in theory it might work. 
PS: haven't test it yet

reference-
https://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2007/09/how-to-sort-python-dictionary-by-keys/